# using fstream style in php

Tags: php, file, filestream

I have been using file streams with c++ for years and can load character strings from a file like this:

```
char a[30],b[30],c[30];
ofstream fp;
fp.open("file.txt");
fp<<a<<b<<c;
```

Is there a way to read strings from a file in PHP in the same fashion without reading a whole line or file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with c++ - what exactly does this code do in c++?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're looking for [**fscanf**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php):

```
$handle = fopen("users.txt", "r");
while ($userinfo = fscanf($handle, "%s\t%s\t%s\n")) {
    list ($name, $profession, $countrycode) = $userinfo;
    //... do something with the values
}
```

One obvious difference is that you have to specify the format as the function argument (it's hard to be *that* reflective when working with dynamic types). The advantage, though, as you may be quite specific in which characters to take in, using formats like `%[0-9]|%[a-zA-Z0-9@&;:,. /!?-]` etc.